# I am not able to parse huge json file by using cjson in effective way but the cjson library is good to implement

Tags: cjson

I want to parse a huge json with more accuracy and less code implementation. Is there any possibility to implement.i am able to parse a huge file into the buffer but when I try to access values of json I need to do individually for all the keys and values. Will there any possibility to retrieve values of objects only when needed. Please provide my example for parsing huge json file and using values

Comment: please show us your efforts

Comment: please help me in conveting following json to c  structure with no segmentation fault

Comment: Kindly show us something navaneetha. Maybe the code which you have tried, or the JSON which you want to parse or what kind of final output you desire.